# Resizeing an oversized image using overflow:hidden and keep the aspect ratio

Tags: css, responsive-design, overflow, image-resizing

I'm creating a responsive gallery and my client sends me image that are landscape and portrait and varies sizes.

I'm trying to create a way to take an inline image and keep the aspect ratio the same by using css.

Here is a link to the code pen I created. Please feel free to edit.

http://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/mpado

The image inside the box is 3137 x 4012 What I'm trying to do is keep the image width at 100% inside the grid_3 by using the class max-img-border.

Then I want the height to keep the same aspect ratio, so the image isn't squished, but hidden.
So for example the top of the tree would be hidden by the overflow:hidden command in the class max-img-border.

How would I achieve this?

Also if you can achieve this, is there a way to add position:center center?

Here is the code if you dont want to look at the code pen.

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div class="tree">

  <div class="grid_3">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Tree_at_Golf_Course.JPG" title="Tree removal">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Tree_at_Golf_Course.JPG" alt="Tree removal" class="max-img-border">
    </a>
    <h5>Tree Removal</h5>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

And here is the css

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color:#1f1f1f;
}

.tree{
    margin:150px auto;
}

.grid_3 {
    width:260px;
    margin:0 20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

.max-img-border {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-height:180px;
    border:solid 2px #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block; 
}

h5 {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:19px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:700;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: you don't set any height to your box, how do you expect to hide somthing , except for the width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use vertical-align and negative margin to virtually reduce height of image.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Grbxg

```
.grid_3 {
    width:260px;
    margin:0 20px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.02);
}

.grid_3 a {
  display:block;  
  height:171px; border:solid 2px #FFFFFF;
  line-height:168px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.max-img-border {
    width:100%;
    margin:-100% 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: But, if you want to keep a ratio on height about the box itself, it can be settled from parent's width, or window's width.


Do you need this box to expand width and height with ratio from window's browser ?

Comment: I need to keep the height of the box the same. so all images in the gallery are equal. Portrait / Verticle image I dont care if the top of the image gets cut off, I just need the box / container to stay the same size. Without squishing the image.

Comment: what height ? ratio of width window ? see this : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj or this  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/KuJDl what you need might be a mix of those 2

Comment: Here is a photo shop comp of what im trying to do.
[link](http://chris.proitservicesllc.com/tree.jpg)

Comment: Here is a link to my gallery to make a little more sense.

[http://chris.proitservicesllc.com/gallery.php](http://chris.proitservicesllc.com/gallery.php)

I think I can learn from your animal clipping code pen though.

Comment: Man I can't figure it out. I've tried a combo of both your pens, but just not getting it. Any way you could take another stab at it?

Comment: hi, just back, if you set a max-height, is it what you look for http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/jgrDh or clipping http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Grbxg ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes!!! This is what I was looking for. [http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Grbxg](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Grbxg) Thank you so much. I appreciate it.