# Pictures in a div

Tags: html, css, image

So I want to write some css so I can make a preset div size that I can put the pictures in. Even if the picture is bigger than the div i would like to make it show only what the div can show you. So kinda like cropping it or something. I want to make a little thumbnail that you can click on and see the whole picture. I have no idea where to start. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432113/crop-centered-image-inside-div

Answer (score 0):

```
.yourDivClass {
    height: #px;
    width: #px;
}

.yourDivClass img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This will create your fixed size div, and then center your image inside the div, with only the size of your div being visible of the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the `width` and `height` will prevent the div from automatically re sizing, and `overflow: hidden` will hide (or crop) everything that excedes the `div`'s boundries

this JSFiddle will show you how the JS, and CSS are really simple...
http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/bh2dz8Lq/
(make sure that you look at the css... it is awfully simple)

Answer (score 0):

```
#divId{
    width: xpx;
    height: xpx;
}
#imgId{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#imgId:hover{
    width: 100%;
}
```

The image will shrink to the size of the div when you hover over it.